# SQL - Group by count - using two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am trying to have a query which will run a headcount of nurses who are rostered to work grouped into their Cost Centre (basically their location, which ward etc.) and which segment of time they fall into(Early Shift, Late etc.)

However sometimes someone from another cost centre can be transferred to a different one and I need to count this into the group as well.

All employees have a home cost centre: HOMELABORLEVLENAME3 and then a column exists called ORGPATHTXT.

ORGPATHTXT is always null unless they are transferred in.

**I need to group together both then segment that as per the shift times.**

My current code is below:

```
select 
HOMELABORLEVELNAME2, HOMELABORLEVELNAME3,

sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-13 04:00' and '2022-05-13 11:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Today_Early',
sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-13 11:00' and '2022-05-13 18:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Today_Late',
sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-13 18:00' and '2022-05-14 04:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Today_Night',

sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-14 04:00' and '2022-05-14 11:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Tmrw_Early',
sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-14 11:00' and '2022-05-14 18:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Tmrw_Late',
sum(CASE WHEN SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-05-14 18:00' and '2022-05-15 04:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Tmrw_Night'

from VP_SCHEDULE s

where

PERSONNUM != 'UNASSIGNEDSHIFT'
and
HOMELABORLEVELNAME2 = '40'
AND (HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1914' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1964' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1924' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1954'
OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1944' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1934' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1554' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1564'
OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1504' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '5334' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '2204' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '3104'
OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '3004' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '2004' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '3304' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '2104'
OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '7554' OR HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 = '1754')
and paycodename is null
-- AND SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-04-29 04:00' and '2022-04-29 11:00'
group by HOMELABORLEVELNAME2, HOMELABORLEVELNAME3
```

This then shows as:
[image: results]

My issue, is that by grouping by HOMELABORLEVELNAME3, it doesn't count the people with ORGPATHTXT filled in, but if I group by ORGPATHTXT I am not grouping by cost centre number which is a requirement. Sorry if this is long winded! But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to simplify your question with some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Need the sample data and expected result to confirm, but sounds like you want a `GROUP BY COALESCE( ORGPATHTXT , HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 )`

Comment: @Squirrel This is my first post here, so sorry for the lack of knowledge but what kind of sample data would help?

Comment: @BrodyCondely you didn't mention what `ORGPATHTXT` has in it when it's populated. If it contains the value that should be used instead of `HOMELABORLEVELNAME3` then @Squirrel s answer would totally work for you.

Comment: also use `in`
eg. `HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 in ('1914','1964','1924','1954', '1944','1934','1554','1564', '1504','5334','2204','3104', '3004','2004','3304','2104', '7554','1754')`

Comment: @NigelThorne Oh! That makes sense, and I think that is where I am struggling. ORGPATHTXT has a text path instead of a number. So as an example: HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 could equal: 1954 but the ORGPATHTXT would be SVHSH/HOSPITALS/SVHT/CLINICAL/ST RAF. ORGPATHTXT is normally NULL, but I need to count that entry IF its not null and it needs to be counted as part of the group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way when ORGPATHTXT is set, to know which HOMELAGORLEVELNAME3 value it should be counted with.

```
select [...]
from vp_schedule s
left join ([... some things that maps ORGPATHTXT to LEVELNAME3 value]) magic 
on s.ORGPATHTXT = magic.ORGPATHTXT
where PERSONNUM != 'UNASSIGNEDSHIFT'
  and s.HOMELABORLEVELNAME2 = '40'
  AND (s.HOMELABORLEVELNAME3 in ('1914','1964','1924','1954', '1944','1934','1554','1564', '1504','5334','2204','3104', '3004','2004','3304','2104', '7554','1754'))
  and paycodename is null
-- AND SHIFTSTARTDATE between '2022-04-29 04:00' and '2022-04-29 11:0
group by 
  HOMELABORLEVELNAME2, 
  COALESCE( magic.HOMELABORLEVELNAME3, s.HOMELABORLEVELNAME3)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, I will play around with this and see how I go. Thank you!